# Sharepoint 2010 - Create Site from Code using Custom Site Template

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am creating a NEW sharepoint site from a silverlight webpart. I am using the ClientContext Model and it is working great for a team site template (STS#0). I need to create a NEW site from a CUSTOM site template that I have created, but I do not know how to reference this template being to specify a web template it is by name and only able to reference one of the standard templates.

Here is my code:

```
  string siteUrl = App.RootSite;
  string siteDescription = project.projectName; // "A new project site.";
  int projectLanguage = 1033;
  string projectTitle = project.projectName; // "Project Web Site";
  string projectUrl = project.projectURL; //"projectwebsite";
  bool projectPermissions = false;
  string webTemplate = "STS#0"; //TODO: reference custom site template

  try
  {
    ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
    Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;

    WebCreationInformation webCreateInfo = new WebCreationInformation();
    webCreateInfo.Description = siteDescription;
    webCreateInfo.Language = projectLanguage;
    webCreateInfo.Title = projectTitle;
    webCreateInfo.Url = projectUrl;
    webCreateInfo.UseSamePermissionsAsParentSite = projectPermissions;
    webCreateInfo.WebTemplate = webTemplate;

    oNewWebsite = oWebsite.Webs.Add(webCreateInfo);

    clientContext.Load(
        oNewWebsite,
        website => website.ServerRelativeUrl,
        website => website.Created,
        website => website.Id);

    clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFail);

  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Loop through all of your available templates, you will find that the custom template name has the guid in front of it: {A13D0D34-EEC2-4BB5-A563-A926F7F9681A}#ProjectSiteTemplate.

```
    ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
    Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;
    WebTemplateCollection templates = oWebsite.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1033, true);

    clientContext.Load(templates);
    clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync(onTemplateSucceeded, null);

private void onTemplateSucceeded(object sender, ClientRequestSucceededEventArgs args)
{
    UpdateUIMethod updateUI = ShowTemplates;
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(updateUI);
}

private void ShowTemplates()
{
    foreach (WebTemplate template in templates)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(template.Id + " : "
          + template.Name + " : "
          + template.Title);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

example 
http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/25/programatically-create-site-from-site-template-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Link is for the server object model; poster is using the client object model